# Join multiple table using generic repository patten with Entity framework with unit of work

Tags: entity-framework, generics, repository, unit-of-work

I am developing a web application using  MVC4 with Entity framework 5.

I have created generic repository for accessing database with unit of work.

Having the below two repository,

- CustomerRepository  - Customer table
- LibraryRepository  - Library table

These two tables are not linked with each other( there is no foreign key relation ).

Want to write a query by combining these repository. Is possible to write a query by combining two different repository?

If yes, please let me know the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your generic repositories expose an IQueryable method, you should be able to use a LINQ join to query both repositories:

```
var items = from c in customerRepository.AsQueryable()
            join l in libraryRepository.AsQueryable() on c.SomeProperty equals l.SomeOtherProperty
            select new { CustomerName = c.FirstName, LibraryName = l.Name };
```

There may be limitations to what the query can do, but I did a quick proof of concept on my own codebase between two separate repositories and it worked just fine (with the expected sql firing).

**Update**

It appears you are attempting two separate queries with a where clause-- I don't believe LINQ2Entities supports what you are attempting to do. Try updating your code to the following:

```
var customer = (
    from cus in _customer.Query()
    join lib in _library.Query()
    on cus.LId equals lib.Id select cus
).ToList();
```

Where you are replacing the two 'from/where' queries with a 'join/on'.

Comment: Please find my code. var customer = (from cus in _customer.Query()
                         from lib in _library.Query()
                         where cus.LId == lib.Id
                         select cus ).ToList();

There is no compile time error. When running the code i got the below  exception. Can you please let me know what i did wrong?

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Customer] Query()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: What types are the variables _customer and _library? That error seems to indicate that they are already IQueryable<>. If that happens to be the case, try removing the .Query() method calls from that statement and try things again.

Comment: _customer, _library is the repository of customer and library table. The Query() methods returns the DBSet object.
      
 Please find the generic repository code below,
   
 public IDbSet<T> ProductDbSet
        {
           get { return _dbSet ?? (_dbSet = BaseDbContext.Set<T>());} 
        }

        public IQueryable<T> Query()
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = ProductDbSet;
            return query;
        }

Comment: After changing query to use 'join', code is working fine. Can you please let me know more about what is the problem when using 'where' queries?

Comment: Glad its working for you (would appreciate accepting it as the answer since it solved your problem). In order for the two where's to work properly, the query would need access to the underlying DbSet's themselves, rather than an IQueryable. With a generic repository interface, that tends to go against the grain. I always use the join method, so perhaps someone else can chime in with the reason?

Comment: excellent i confirm that works. I added this in my repository base: `public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> AsQuerable()
        {
            return _unitOfWork.CreateSet<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
        }`

Comment: OMG! I'm sorry, but I almost cry LOL! That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank U very much !